# Can't pass int value between two activities

Tags: java, android, int, bundle

I tried to pass values from my main activity to my finish activity but I always got error in my finish activity. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Here's my code from my Level1 class:

**Note:** the Chronometer is already defined at the top of my activity, before onCreate method.

```
private void showElapsedTime() {
    chrono.start();
    long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase();            
    int hours = (int) (timeElapsed / 3600000);
    int minutes = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
    int seconds = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;
    int seco = seconds;

    Toast.makeText(this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + seconds, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent a = new Intent (this, Finish.class);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("sec", seco);
    a.putExtras(b);
}
```

and this one is my Finish.class code:

```
Set1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time1);
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

Set1.setText("time: " + b.getInt("seco"));
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathattack/com.example.mathattack.Finish}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.example.mathattack.Finish.onCreate(Finish.java:33)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-20 11:37:49.345: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is in line 33 in finish calss.

Comment: you put sec, but you try accessing seco.

Comment: @JoshM I just tried it. By accessing seconds, I got the same error.

Comment: @Aravinth It's the Set1.setText("time: " + b.getInt("seco"));

Comment: try this Intent intent = new
Intent(getApplicationContext(),finnish.class);
intent.putExtra("sec",seco);  
startActivity(intent);    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
int tmp = extras.getString("sec");

Comment: If I'll declare startActivity, it will just go to finish. user has something to do in level1 class, it's the level1 of the game.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri it's the Set1.setText("time: " + b.getInt("seco"));

Comment: 1) If user has to do something in level 1, then when ever user is done doing that, then only start the finish activity. 2) that is because `seco` does not exist, so throwing error. Check for null then only extras the extrats from the bundle.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri seco exists, try to look it above. I declared it, with the same value as the seconds.

Comment: If you see docs of [putInt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), then then the left argument is your key. So you need to extract the extras using that key. You assign a value to the key and extract from it. I agree seco exists but its not the key, right? You declared `b.putInt("sec", seco);`. here `sec` seems to be the key as @Josh M correctly pointed out before.

Comment: I tried seconds. Same thing, it doesn't display the seconds in the textView at Finish.class.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use `SharedPreferences` and save the data in your main activity, and get the data in your finish activity.

Comment: @Insanity I tried sharedPreferences last time, it won't work also.

Comment: I noticed that you are casting seconds to an int. With that math, it probably doesn't come out even. Maybe try the code with it as a double, and send the double through. (I think you can do that, not sure)

Comment: @pingboo23 try this String seconds = String.valueOf(val);  Set1.setText("time: " + seconds);

Comment: @Insanity I just get that code from one of the post here in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Aravinth it doesn't work.

Comment: @pingboo23 I would also log what the value of seconds actually is, I'm wondering if it is actually an int.

Comment: @Insanity how can I log the value?

Comment: @pingboo23 `Log.i("Seconds", "The value of seconds is: " + seconds);` Then import log and run it and look in your logcat for the tag "Seconds" and see what the value is.

Comment: @Insanity `the value of seconds is 0;the value of seconds is 0;the value of seconds is 8;` .. this is what it says in the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Your `int` is stored under the name "sec". Try using the line below to retrieve it.

`Set1.setText("time: " + String.valueOf(b.getInt("sec")));`

Comment: If this is incorrect an explanation as to why, instead of just a down vote, would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is the line your exception points to then either Set1 or b is null. Without seeing the rest of your method we can't say.

Comment: It's only the codes that matters to the chronometer. Others is just for the game itself.

Comment: Which activity are you generating the Text View in? You may need to pass a reference for it along so that it can be modified.

Comment: `TextView` is in my Finish class.

Answer (score 1):

its a good idea to check if extras is null before actually extracting it:

```
if (b!= null) {
    int val = b.getInt("sec");
    Set1.setText("time: " + String.valueOf(val));
}
```

Comment: I tried this one, no errors but still it doesn't set the value of seconds in my textView at finish.class.

Comment: It won't set it. It will only set when you call `startActivity` with that particular intent. Since you are not starting Finish Activity with that intent, it won't set it. If you want to just share some value in between 2 classes you can use `SharedPreference`.

Comment: I tried SharedPreference last time, but it doesn't work. So, where should I put the startActivity?

Comment: Whenever you are done with your current activity and want to start the Finish Activity. If you are calling this `showElapsedTime` with aim of opening a new activity, then just call it after you declare the `a.putExtras(b);`.  Simply `startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Try to log  the value of `seco` where you are setting it. As @Aravint pointed, it might be due to casting in int.

Comment: How can I log the value? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `Log.d("TAG", value);`

Comment: the value of seconds is 0;the value of seconds is 0;the value of seconds is 8; .. this is what it says in the logcat.

Comment: @pingboo23 Perhaps you should call `chrono.start();` in the `onCreate()` method. When you start it in the `showElapsedTime()` method, then immediately open Finish.class, basically no time has elapsed.

Comment: I tried to call `chrono.start();` in the onCreate method. Still, `seconds` doesn't display on the finish class. How can I possibly get the last value of the seconds that i found on the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

**you can also try using a object you can put the variable you want to use in other activity before oncreate method like so that i can be used by other classes also.**

```
public class ... extends Activity { 

     int p; // int which you want to share.

 @Override

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       ........
       }
}
```

**and in next class you can use this by:**

```
MainActivity mn = new MainActivity ();

System.out.println(mn.p);
```

Comment: I can't access `seconds` through this.

Comment: you can make another variable before oncreate and assign it like int m = secconds